# How to show : $ \int_0^\infty \bigl(1+ x^2\bigr)^{-1/2}\; dx < \infty$

Tags: calculus

I want to show an integral calculation converges.

Does $$ \int_0^\infty \bigl(1+ x^2\bigr)^{-1/2}\; dx $$ converge?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+0+to+infinity+of+%281%2Bx%5E2%29%5E%28-1%2F2%29

Comment: @AlexL I typically don't like the links to WA. For once the students don't learn anything from that, and sometimes (rarely) WA is wrong... How can one guess when WA is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estimate from below: For $x\geq 1$: $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2x^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}x}.$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** When $x \to \infty$

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} \sim \frac{1}{x}$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

> Let $\lim_{x\to\infty}x^pf(x)=A$. Then $$\int_a^{\infty}f(x)dx$$ converges if $p>1$ and $A$ is finite.

Comment: /+/+/+/best hint✓

Answer (score 1):

Indefinite integral of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$:

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx = \ln(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})$$

which clearly diverges.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^{\infty} (1+x^2)^{-1/2}.dx=\int_0^{\pi/2} \sec \theta . d\theta$$

And this would diverge.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : $x\mapsto (1+x^2)^{-\frac 12}$ is positive continuous function on $\Bbb R_+$ and you have $(1+x^2)^{-\frac 12}\sim x^{-1}$ when $x\to +\infty$